# IIS 6.0 Testing Environment in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, windows-7, iis-6

Trying to develop and test an ASP.NET MVC 2 as well as a hosted WCF app where the client is limited to IIS 6.0 (OS Windows 2003). I am developing and testing in Windows 7 which has IIS 7. I do not have access to a Windows 2003 disk, so creating a VM doesn't appear to be a viable option for me...

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated

Update:
Lucas' response led me to consider a virtual dedicated server... Going to try that for a testing environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have many options

1. You bend (get a MSDN subscription or Win 2k3)
2. Your client bends (upgrades to Win7/2k8)
3. Find someone you know who can let you use an IIS 6 machine.
4. Get your client to let you use one of their machines during development

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... I do have a "WebSite Spark" subscription, but it only has WIndows 2008 available for me...

Comment: @Bryce Fischer  I added a fourth option.

Comment: Thanks. That is actually what I had asked, but I'm working remotely, and they are quite paranoid about VPN. I think I have them convinced to purchase me a copy of Win 2k3...

Answer (score 0):

You can virtual PC it.  If you can use Windows XP, M$ provides a virtual machine + WinXP trial. It's more for using IE6 I think, but I don't think it limits application installation like IIS.

I don't have the link anymore, but it's provided by M$ from their download area